# An htaccess Rewrite rule that takes into account two parts of a URL, such as example.com/place/name

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to create a `.htaccess` `rewrite rule` where by my URL `http://example.com/place/name` is treated such that the file `place.php` is called and it has available to it the parameter `name`.

I'm fairly confident of rewriting just one part with `RewriteRule ^place$ place.php [L]`, however am unsure how to achieve the two part process outlined above.

The first `place` part will always refer to one of three static files, and the second name part will be unknown and different each request.

How might I achieve this?

Comment: `place` is the PHP script file name and it is a variable. Right? Now, what kind of parameter is `name`? A value to what key in the query: `place.php?what=name`

Comment: @faa Well its arbitrary really, just call it t, so /places.php?t=name

Answer (score 1):

You may try this in one .htaccess file  in your root directory

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  .*/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?   [NC]
RewriteRule .*       %1.php?t=%2                   [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm having other problems with my htaccess so can't test your rule just this second until i've fixed those but it looks good! Thanks again.

Comment: @Rodgers Just try to let me know how it goes when you test it.